# Why is my player not moving (CMMotionManager) by Tilting the screen (SWIFT 3)?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3, cmmotionmanager

I am trying to using the option of tilting the screen to move my player.
However, i followed the instructions of Ray Wenderlich and his space invaders
tutorial. I just can't seem to figure it out..

Please have a look at it to help me out.

I had to add them as images since for magical reason i just can upload the code :( probably my lack of coding skills..

[Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRSCe.png)
[Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnReF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly what you are trying to do, with his code of tilting you'll run into a lot of problems depending on device orientation and position especially if you change the position of device after its already started. I suggest doing a touch to move or maybe touch left side touch right side to move your character, its easier to implement and easier to control.